# Modify scroll direction to horizontal in mobile

Tags: html, css, scroll, media-queries, scroll-snap

I have a webpage with multiple sections each of them doing 100% width and 100 viewport height.
I've also set a scrollsnap on each of them.
The scrollsnap happens from top to bottom, however on mobile version I would like the direction of the content to be set horizontally so the user will scroll from left to right.

Is there any way to do this with mediaqueries ?

IN DESKTOP

```
 ------
| 100vh|
| 100vw|
|      |
|   ↓  |
 ------
 Scrollsnap
 ------
| 100vh|
|100vw |
|      |
|   ↓  |
 ------
 Scrollsnap
 ------
|100vh |
|100vw |
|      |
|   ↓  |
 ------
```

IN MOBILE

```
 ------            ------            ------    
|100vh |          |100vh |          |100vh |
|100vw |          |100vw |          |100vw |
|      |Scrollsnap|      |Scrollsnap|      |
|   →  |      →   |   →  |     →    |  →   |
|      |          |      |          |      |
 ------            ------            ------
```

Edit :

Thanks for your answers with the scrollsnap X , However i would like to know how to make all the section side by side in the body on mobile. Scroll snap is just to add some context

here is a codepen with my code. Each section is videos so it's a lot of code to post in here https://codepen.io/knudsem/pen/LYZqwdo

Comment: insert code is here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that on mobile adding the **`x-mandatory`** or **`x-proximity`** property to the body.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory; // or x-proximity, whichever you prefer
    }

    section {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
}
```